# Playing with memory in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault

This is bit of a strange one...I've written a very short bit of code to allocate some memory for an integer, save a value to it and print out the memory address where it is saved:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (void) {

    int * b = new int;

    *b = 12345;

    cout << "   -> *b = " << *b << endl;
    cout << "   ->  b = " <<  b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Lets say this returns the following:

```
-> *b = 123456
->  b = 0x7f9429c04bf0
```

So far as I know there is no reason why this value is not still chilling in memory as I didn't actively remove it - so, just for fun, I try and run the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (void) {

    int * b = reinterpret_cast <int*> (0x7f9429c04bf0);

    cout << "   -> *b = " << *b << endl;
    cout << "   ->  b = " <<  b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which throws a segfault - does anyone know why this isn't allowed?  I mean...it clearly isn't a good idea and I have no plans to use it in practise but I am curious.
Cheers!
Jack

Comment: You are using the `new` operator which is `C++`, yet your question is tagged `C`. Please use correct tags.

Comment: you are entering undefined behavior.

Comment: that memory section may not valid in another run. randomized addressing is a memory protection mechanism.

Comment: @dandan78 has the right idea in their answer. You can read about [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) to learn more about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Process runs in its own address space, the address ur passing to **reinterpret_cast** should be accessible in the **address space** of the current process, which it isn't as the second process has a **different address space** layout. Also, each iteration of even the first program will give u different addresses, which is the whole point of **ASLR(Address Space Layout Randomization)**, that is, to **randomize** key parts of the process memory on each new instance. Having static addresses, as used to be the case pre-ASLR, would cause havoc, leading to easy exploitation of vulnerable programs.

Read More about ASLR: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization
Virtual Memory:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Answer (score 7):

Each process has its own virtual memory space separate from other processes. When the process terminates, its memory is reclaimed by the operating system.

The reason it's throwing a segfault is because the OS is unhappy with your program trying to access memory that does not belong to it.

The whole idea behind having protected memory is to isolate processes so that they *can't* mess with each other's memory and cause nastiness to happen. And even if you could access random memory locations, you wouldn't really find anything interesting there. It's basically the same kind of stuff you get when accessing an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: Ok so it is caused by the OS being protective.  That makes sense, I was just curious if there was a way to force the issue as a little experiment with memory

Answer (score 1):

Even if you ran both programs at once I would hope you got kicked for that, in stead of getting the right answer.  The implication that you think I should be able to access another programs data by guessing addresses is scary, although if you want some history, there used to be a game called "core wars" which involved doing exactly that to try to make each other crash ...

I suppose the real answer is that this has "undefined behaviour" and you should be grateful it didn't just implode.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern C++ platforms work with *virtual* memory provided by the underlying OS. Virtual memory is not a trivial physical form of storage you seem to believe it is. Virtual memory is just an imaginary conceptual storage that exists only as long as the process runs. It simulates "memory-like" behavior every time you access your process address space.

Your access to `0x7f9429c04bf0` is not access to physical memory address, it is access to the process virtual address space, which will be redirected to some physical location that you cannot predict.

And when your process ends, its virtual memory disappears forever. It was simulated anyway, fake in a sense. When you start another process, it gets its own virtual memory that has no connection to the old one whatsoever. In that new process access to `0x7f9429c04bf0` will lead to some other physical location you cannot predict (or, as in your case, crash, if `0x7f9429c04bf0` is not even valid).

To expect that your value is "still chilling in memory" would be rather naive. In fact, your value has never really been in any "memory" suitable for any kind of "chilling".